# Как сделать, чтобы программа, скомпиленная с помощью pyinstaller, работала в фоне компьютера?

Tags: python, windows, exe

Создаю програму на Python, которая передаёт информацию о компьютере по локальной сети на другой (оба компьютера на windows). Возникла проблема с образованием удобной мне форме EXE-файла. Кто разбирается в этом, подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы программа, скомпиленная с помощью pyinstaller, работала в **фоне** компьютера? Дело в том, что к работающей программе прилагается окно для взаимодействия с ней, что мне не нужно. Как от него избавиться?

Comment: Добавь её в планировщик

Comment: запустить как сервис

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я ещё немножко покопался в инструкции к pyinstaller, нашёл опцию noconsole, при использовании которой консоль не появляется. Синтаксис команды к pyinstaller будет примерно таков:

```
pyinstaller --noconsole main.py
```

Всем спасибо за ваши ответы

Answer (score 1):

```
pyinstaller -F -w file.py
```

где:

- `-F` - сборка в один файл,
- `-w` - без консоли.